# MIPS how to processing on 64 bit binary after MULT (32 bit) operand conveniently?

Tags: assembly, mips

The code will give a 64 bit number in mips, stored in `$HI` and `$LO`.

```
MULT $s1, $s2
```

If my result of this `MULT` is a 64 bit number stored in `$HI` and `$LO`, how can I use the results to continue dividing or adding to other values?

Is shifting them with `MFHI` / `MFLO` into the 2 temp register and processing the high and low bits separately the only way to do arithmetic on the results?

Comment: If you have a 64-bit capable MIPS (MIPS III or later, or MIPS64), you can of course combine the two 32-bit halves into one 64-bit integer register with double-word shift / or instructions after mflo / mfhi.  Otherwise yes you need to implement extended-precision manually if you want it.

Comment: so there's only manual algo to do it ?

Comment: Basically yes, that's one reason *why* it's nice to have a 64-bit CPU.  Especially on MIPS where there's no carry flag.

Comment: urgh i am learning mips, I don't have a choice :(

Comment: MIPS has had 64-bit instructions since [MIPS III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS_III) in 1991.  If you're on modern MIPS32 (without 64-bit registers), you'd normally use a different instruction than mult.  Especially if you don't need extended precision and can just use the low 32 bits of the multiply result, like in C how you'd often do `int32_t prod = a * b;` instead of `int64_t prod = a * (int64_t)b;` to get the full result of 32x32 => 64-bit multiplication.  Extended precision with only 2 chunks is not bad, though, except for division by a number wider than 32 bits.